# Global match regular expression with Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I am searching in Neo4j using a regular expression. I would like this search to be global. As it stands, the search will only find words that *start* with inputted letters in the regular expression:

```
MATCH (a) 
WHERE a.name =~ '(?i)bob.+' 
RETURN a.name
```

So it will find the name `Bob Smith` no problem, but it will not find `John McBobberson`. How do I find John McBobberson while retaining the input "bob" as the search query?

Comment: BTW please try to use labels instead of a match across every node

Comment: @Luanne Certainly! I was just trying to make it easier for the example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (a) 
WHERE a.name =~ '(?i).*bob.+' 
RETURN a.name
```

should find John McBobberson, but I don't think it will find John McBob. This one should find both.

```
MATCH (a) 
WHERE a.name =~ '(?i).*bob.*' 
RETURN a.name
```